# How to reduce memory usages while loading sprite sequences of images in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, sprite-sheet

I've made a *.swf file of the sprite sequences of 1000 images with (780 x 480) size. After that I embed this with another one class to show but every time it crushes during run time because of insufficient memory (assume that I have 2GB memory space). Which is the best way to implement such big sprite sequences in AS3 by avoiding the memory problem? Please help if you have any good suggestions.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 780x480 @ 72 dpi with 24 bit color is around 1 meg each so your trying to embed over 1 gig of images in your swf. Your users are going to have to download all that before they can use your software.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to load them all at a time in memory. That is a huge amount of memory. You really don't need 1000 images at a time. May be you can load 10 - 20 at once and while running the sequence remove the previous onces from memory. In this way you can reduce the memory footprint.

And are you embedding 1000 images in the main swf? What is the size of the swf in that case? That will be huge and user have to wait too long to load. Instead of embedding in main swf, dynamically loading the images might be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks. But how to take these kind of sprite sequences. Assume that the swf file is 36.5 MB but when I play this it's taking around 2GB of my PC's memory. Please help (if possible), to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Embad, and how will user download that huge swf? If you're targeting flash (not AIR) I think it'll be better to store images on server, and download them by request. If you're targeting AIR, do as Marty propses: devide swf into smaller swfs.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me any example code to fix this problem please. Assume that it not AIR. A web based flash apps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hm. I think you should a closer look at [flash.net.URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply made a video of your images ?

Comment: You can play a streamed video : http://flashthusiast.com/2008/03/02/loading-and-displaying-video-in-actionscript-30-no-more-video-objects/